# i want to search filter my database values using checkboxes php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, search, checkbox

[image]by using this code i can now fetch pro_price table but i need multiple column saerch. this is my working code for an solo column, but i need to fetch two column more from that table. How i can i do that. please help

Database name: **auction**

Table name : **addproduct**

Column names : **pro_price, pro_code, hsn_code**

This is my code,

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['search'])){
$pro_price = $_REQUEST['pro_price'];
foreach ($_REQUEST['pro_price'] as $pro_price) {
    $statearray[] = mysql_real_escape_string($pro_price);
}
$states = implode ("','", $statearray);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM addproduct WHERE pro_price IN ('$states'))";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0)
{
    echo "Sorry, but we can not find an entry to match your query...<br><br>";
}
else
{
    echo "<table border='1' width='900' class='srchrslt'>
    <tr class='head'>
    <td>pro_name</td>
    <td>pro_brand</td>
    <td>hsn_code</td>
    <td>pro_tax2</td>
    <td>pro_tax3</td>
    </tr>";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ))
    {              
        echo "<tr>";

        echo "<td>" . $row['pro_name'] . " </td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['pro_brand'] . " </td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['hsn_code'] . " </td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['pro_tax2'] . " </td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['pro_tax3'] . " </td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
```

}

please help...and thank you

Comment: Please provide more details about your question. You are already selection all values form table, so it will provide all results matched with your condition.Where you want to fetch two more parameters in condition. please explain.

Comment: @sonamgupta I am working searching from the database through multiple check boxes. here by doing this code, i get only the pro_price as under my checkbox. I need to use pro_code & hsn_code also for my multiple searches

Comment: So you do have posted multiple checked values on that page the first get all that values like pro_price and then add it with and in where clause.

Comment: Stop using PHP's deprecated and insecure mysql_ API

Answer (score 1):

You do a SELECT *, which returns all columns in a table. In your case, it seems there's only a single column, so either you need to add additional columns to the table, or alternatively, you need to figure out whether perhaps you have not been granted permissions to see all columns in the table.

UPDATE:

It seems what you really want to do is add additional search criteria. This would mean your query would become something like the following:

```
SELECT * FROM addproduct WHERE pro_price IN ('$states') OR pro_code IN ('$codes')
```

For that to work, you would have to do what you already with the selected prices (i.e. store them i a variable called $states). In the SQL line above, I assume you store the selected values of the codes in a similar variable called `$codes`.

The full code with this addition would be something like tis:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['search'])){
$pro_price = $_REQUEST['pro_price'];
$pro_code = $_REQUEST['pro_code'];
foreach ($_REQUEST['pro_price'] as $pro_price) {
    $statearray[] = mysql_real_escape_string($pro_price);
}
foreach ($_REQUEST['pro_code'] as $pro_code) {
    $codesarray[] = mysql_real_escape_string($pro_code);
}
$states = implode ("','", $statearray);
$codes = implode ("','", $codesarray);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM addproduct WHERE pro_price IN ('$states') OR pro_code IN ('$codes')";
```

Note that I'm not a PHP coder, so it is entirely possible the code can be optimized. I just wanted to show you what I think would work.

Comment: iam alredy taking all the values from the table **addproduct**  by using `$sql = "SELECT * FROM addproduct WHERE pro_price IN ('$states'))";` i need to know how to retrieve two or more column from table, like i fetched **pro_price**.where i need to change my code ???

Comment: That's what I'm saying; you get every column in the table by using `SELECT *`. There are no other columns. The table appears to have the columns you already extract (`SELECT *` in this case is the equivalent of doing `SELECT pro_name, pro_brand, hsn_code, pro_tax2, pro_tax3`). If you suspect there are other columns, you either already have them in your recordset and need to show them by adding them to the HTML table, or you might not have permission to see the columns.

Comment: I am working searching from the database through multiple check boxes. here by doing this code, i get only the pro_price as under my checkbox. I need to use pro_code & hsn_code also for my multiple searches

Comment: That part was not clear from your question. So to recap, you actually want to add more columns to your search criteria?

Comment: i dont know to rewrite this code correctly, i currently working on ftp access, so i cant do any errors. can you please help to overcome this

Comment: i know where to rewrite the codes but don't know how to, i think the changes will be in line 2, 3, 4, 7 ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152710/discussion-between-yahiya-and-schmitzit).

Answer (score 0):

At last  I got the solutions to my question. Thanks to @SchmitzIT who had supported me. Iam posting the code for further candidates.

**index.php**

```
<form name="search" method="post" action="searchplant">
<table width="900" border="1" class="srch">
<tr class="head"><td>Pro Price</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>
<input type="checkbox" value="250" name="pro_price[]">250<br />
<input type="checkbox" value="80" name="pro_price[]">80<br />
<input type="checkbox" value="50" name="pro_price[]">50<br />
<input type="checkbox" value="40" name="pro_price[]">40<br />
<input type="checkbox" value="299" name="pro_price[]">299<br />
<td>
</tr>
<tr class="head"><td>hsncode</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>
<input type="checkbox" value="101101" name="hsn_code[]">101101<br />
<input type="checkbox" value="101102" name="hsn_code[]">101102<br />
<input type="checkbox" value="101103" name="hsn_code[]">101103<br />
<input type="checkbox" value="101104" name="hsn_code[]">101104<br />
<input type="checkbox" value="101105" name="hsn_code[]">101105<br />
<td>
</tr>
<tr class="head"><td>procode</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>
<input type="checkbox" value="101" name="pro_code[]">101<br />
<input type="checkbox" value="102" name="pro_code[]">102<br />
<input type="checkbox" value="103" name="pro_code[]">103<br />
<input type="checkbox" value="104" name="pro_code[]">104<br />
<input type="checkbox" value="105" name="pro_code[]">105<br />
<td>
</tr>
<tr><td colspan="3" align="Right">
<input type="submit" name="search" value="Search" /></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
</div><!-- end service-->
<div id="media" class="group">
```

**search.php**

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['search']))
{
    $pro_price = $_REQUEST['pro_price'];
    $pro_code = $_REQUEST['pro_code'];
    $hsn_code = $_REQUEST['hsn_code'];
    foreach ($_REQUEST['pro_price'] as $pro_price) {
        $statearray[] = mysql_real_escape_string($pro_price);
    }
    foreach ($_REQUEST['pro_code'] as $pro_code) {
        $codesarray[] = mysql_real_escape_string($pro_code);
    }
    foreach ($_REQUEST['hsn_code'] as $hsn_code) {
        $hsnarray[] = mysql_real_escape_string($hsn_code);
    }
    $states = implode ("','", $statearray);
    $codes = implode ("','", $codesarray);
    $hsn = implode ("','", $hsnarray);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM addproduct WHERE pro_price IN ('$states') OR pro_code IN ('$codes') OR hsn_code IN ('$hsn')";

    //Now we search for our search term, in the field the user specified
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

    //This counts the number or results - and if there wasn't any it gives them a     little     message explaining that
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0)
    {
        echo "Sorry, but we can not find an entry to match your query...<br><br>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<table border='1' width='900' class='srchrslt'>
        <tr class='head'>
        <td>pro_name</td>
        <td>pro_brand</td>
        <td>hsn_code</td>
        <td>pro_price</td>
        <td>pro_code</td>
        </tr>";

        //And we display the results
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ))
        {              
            echo "<tr>";

            echo "<td>" . $row['pro_name'] . " </td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['pro_brand'] . " </td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['hsn_code'] . " </td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['pro_price'] . " </td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['pro_code'] . " </td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
    }
}
```

Just change the database name, table name, column name and values according to your data.

Hope you find this useful